# Integrating Backend API with Tea Stack Front-End (TailwindCSS, Eleventy, AlpineJS)

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css, alpine.js, web-frameworks, eleventy

In my new project, I'm learning about new front-end frameworks and libraries and found the Tea Stack (TailwindCSS, Eleventy, AlpineJS). I really liked the idea of this minimal stack (I have very little experience with React and VueJS).

The problem is that besides that I have a back-end server (web server API) and now I need to integrate this back-end (for login authentication, get data for the pages, ...) with the front-end (Tea Stack).

What frameworks and/or libraries am I missing? That could be integrated alongside with what I already have and follows the same idea of a minimalist approach. Since I already have a back-end I didn't want a full stack framework like NodeJS, Laravel, React, ...

I already look some interesting libs like Axios for API access, but it seems that will not be enough for handling the authentication (login page, restriction of pages before login). And for store some sensitive data access of some APIs (like user/pass for fetch authenticated data).

Comment: Eleventy is a static site generator. If you only have an API backend, then you will need a full stack frontend framework with client side rendering, etc. Alpine.js is not a full stack framework. So you can go with backend API + full stack frontend framework, or you can go with server side rendered templates enhanced with Alpine.js for client side interactivity. Have a look at [HTMX](https://htmx.org/docs/) as well, that works well with server side frameworks, with it you can create an SPA-like experience at the frontend without a full stack SPA framework.

Comment: @Dauros Thanks for the info, I look into the [HTMX](https://htmx.org/docs/) that you mentioned and look very interesting. Now I trying  to use Flask + HTMX + TailwindCSS and it's looking good so far.